# Excel 2013 VBA copying a range from 1 spreadsheet and copy to range in 2nd spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an Error 1004 and not sure why. I use this similar code in another workbook, and now I can't seem to find out what's going on. Would anyone be able to explain to me why I'm getting the error? I've researched the internet, but doesn't seem to help.

```
Dim strNameMR As String, strSht As String
Dim chCell, chRng As Range

Worksheets("Master MR").Select
nRpt = Worksheets("Master MR").Range("O2").Value
dRpt = Worksheets("Master MR").Range("N4").Value
wRpt = Worksheets("Master MR").Range("A4").Value
cdRpt = Format(dRpt, "mm-dd-yyyy")

If Worksheets("Master MR").Range("O2").Value > 0 Then
        strNameMR = "MR" & " " & cdRpt & " " & "(" & nRpt & ")"
End If

strSht = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = strNameMR
Sheets(strSht).Range("A1:N96").Copy
'I get the runtime error 1004 below on next line' 
Sheets(strNameMR).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Sheets(strNameMR).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

In another workbook, this code seems to work just fine. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Some of the cells in the range being copied, are multiple cells merged in to one. That didn't matter before when I used the above code. Thanks

Comment: Merged cells are bad, bad, bad and should be avoided. If your code runs fine on unmerged cells and breaks on merged cells, then you have your answer: Don't use merged cells. Use "Center across selection" for horizontal alignment, and use formatting instead of merging for vertically merged cells.

Comment: I think you may be right. Is it possible to copy the column & row widths and paste to the new sheet?

Comment: Yes. Select the whole columns, copy, then paste as special, Formats. Select the whole rows, copy, then paste as special, Formats.

Comment: Awesome! I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! It works great but one question. I have a macro button that deletes all worksheets in the workbook, but while deleting the sheets, Excel keeps giving a question about deleting, because some of the cell have formulas. Is there any way to delete the sheets and not have Excel ask about the formulas?

Comment: The code I have is as follows:

Comment: add `application.displayAlerts = False` at the start, and then turn it back on at the end with `application.displayAlerts = True`

Comment: Worked like a champ! Thanks Fernando!